# How to get the angle of the reset object through Python

Tags: python

The rotation angle of many objects in the scene has been reset. I want to get the correct rotation angle of objects. Can you provide some ideas
[image]

[image]

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking for... can you add more details and explain your problem?

Comment: `bpy.context.object.rotation_euler.z`

Comment: If you enable [Python Tooltips](https://imgur.com/a/BDMAhto) in the Preferences interface menu it will show you the value when you hover over most values in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in automatic way, because how does Blender know where the face-direction of the object? You can do several things.

1. In case if the objects are the same (only rotated in different ways) you can link data of the objects, so that they will share the same model. To do so, select all models with the same shape, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> ⇾ Object Data.
   Objects will share the same model, and you will see, that some of them should be rotated back in object mode.
2. There is an option to rotate the orientation of the object while keeping mesh in place. To activate it, select affect only origins in options popover:

[image]

Then rotate the object's origin accordingly.

Comment: Actually, thank you very much